# Usage of Webgrease for commercial hosting services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, webgrease

Usage of web grease library which is licensed under MS.NET Library license

I have created a basic MVC application which has the Optimization library and its dependency WebGrease library. While I am trying to get this hosted on my company's server I have been notified that I cannot use the webgrease library as the license has the following terms.

**use the software for commercial software hosting services.**

Full license terms are here
https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/aspnetcomponent_rtw_ENU.htm
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebGrease/

My questions are:

1. Would keeping this library for commercial software hosting cause problems?
2. Are there any alternative solutions available for MVC bundling and minification